# javah error: package does not exist with gradle and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, javah

I'm facing an error when compiling my Java sources to produce C++ headers recently: `javah` spits a `package does not exist` error for some file.

**tl;dr:** `javah` works fine for a Java source but not another one – which import clauses are pretty close; `gradle` does not process some libraries but even the packages of the processed ones get flagged as missing.

---

I don't know why javah has started spitting that error since it worked well until recently and I did not change anything special. I'm using `gradle` with Android Studio's `gradle-wrapper`. I recently updated the wrapper's distribution from 2.2.1 to 2.10 but I don't think that's why javah fails now.

According to the logs and the present files, javah doesn't find the packages from libraries I'm using as it compiles `ClassB` but not `ClassA`.

Let's take two examples: `com.batch.android` and `com.adjust.sdk`

- `com.batch.android` library **does** get processed by gradle so its jars **are** in my `build/intermediates/exploded-aar` folder (under com.batch.android/batch-sdk/1.5.3/jars/classes.jar and com.batch.android/batch-sdk/1.5.3/jars/libs/batch.jar)
- `com.adjust.sdk` library **does not** get processed by gradle so its jars **are not** in my build/intermediates/exploded-aar
- both are in my ~/.gradle/cache/ folder
- both packages fail as missing by javah
- both packages are not imported from `ClassA` and `ClassB` java files

Thanks for your help!

---

The gradle logs (sorry guys, it's super long):

```
Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDevAmazonDebugSources, :app:generateDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDevAmazonDebugUnitTestDependencies,     :app:assembleDevAmazonDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
Generating assets binaries
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
Cleaning project...
:app:clean
:app:processAssets
:app:copyFiles
:app:preBuild
:app:preDevAmazonDebugBuild
:app:checkDevAmazonDebugManifest
:app:preDevAmazonReleaseBuild
:app:preDevGoogleDebugBuild
:app:preDevGoogleReleaseBuild
:app:preProdAmazonDebugBuild
:app:preProdAmazonReleaseBuild
:app:preProdGoogleDebugBuild
:app:preProdGoogleReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72320Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex100Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42320Library
:app:prepareComBatchAndroidBatchSdk153Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers136Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta114Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics255Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore238Library
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsNdk112Library
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4101Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidExoplayerExoplayerR142Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet780Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable780Library
:app:prepareComMopubMopubSdk440Library
:app:prepareComZendeskBelvedere1011Library
:app:prepareComZendeskSdk1512Library
:app:prepareComZendeskSdkProviders1512Library
:app:prepareIoBranchSdkAndroidLibrary1112Library
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1310Library
:app:prepareDevAmazonDebugDependencies
:app:compileDevAmazonDebugAidl
:app:compileDevAmazonDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDevAmazonDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDevAmazonDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDevAmazonDebugAssets
:app:processDevAmazonDebugManifest
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDevAmazonDebug
:app:generateDevAmazonDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDevAmazonDebugGoogleServices
:app:generateDevAmazonDebugResources
:app:mergeDevAmazonDebugResources
:app:processDevAmazonDebugResources
:app:generateDevAmazonDebugSources
:app:preDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestBuild
:app:prepareDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDevAmazonDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevAmazonDebugUnitTestBuild
:app:prepareDevAmazonDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:javahBuild_ClassA
:app:javahBuild_ClassB
Error: package com.adjust.sdk does not exist
Error: package com.adjust.sdk does not exist
Error: package com.amazon.ags.api does not exist
Error: package com.batch.android does not exist
Error: package com.batch.android does not exist
Error: package com.crashlytics.android does not exist
Error: package com.crashlytics.android.answers does not exist
Error: package com.crashlytics.android.answers does not exist
Error: package com.crashlytics.android.answers does not exist
Error: package com.mopub.common does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.feedback.impl does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.model.access does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.model.access does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.model.push does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.network.impl does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.network.impl does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.network.impl does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.network.impl does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.network.impl does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.requests does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.storage does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.sdk.support does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.service does not exist
Error: package com.zendesk.service does not exist
Error: package org.joda.time does not exist
Error: package org.joda.time does not exist
Error: package org.joda.time does not exist
Error: package org.joda.time does not exist
Error: package org.joda.time.format does not exist
Error: package org.joda.time.format does not exist
Error: package io.branch.indexing does not exist
Error: package io.branch.referral does not exist
Error: package io.branch.referral does not exist
Error: package io.branch.referral does not exist
Error: package io.branch.referral.util does not exist
Error: package io.branch.referral.util does not exist
Error: package com.adjust.sdk does not exist
Error: package com.amazon.ags.api does not exist
Error: package com.amazon.ags.api does not exist
Error: package com.amazon.ags.api does not exist
Error: package com.amazon.ags.api does not exist
Error: package com.applovin.sdk does not exist
Error: package com.batch.android does not exist
Error: package com.crashlytics.android does not exist
Error: package com.crashlytics.android.ndk does not exist
Error: package io.branch.referral does not exist
Error: package io.branch.referral does not exist
Error: package io.fabric.sdk.android does not exist
Error: package com.google.android.gms.analytics does not exist
Error: package com.google.android.gms.analytics does not exist
Error: package com.google.android.gms.analytics does not exist
Error: package com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier does not exist
Error: package com.google.android.gms.common does not exist
Error: package com.mopub.common does not exist
Error: package com.mopub.common does not exist
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MoPubErrorCode
  location: package com.mopub.mobileads
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MoPubRewardedVideoListener
  location: package com.mopub.mobileads
Error: package com.chartboost.sdk does not exist
Error: package com.adjust.sdk does not exist
Error: package com.adjust.sdk does not exist
Error: package com.adjust.sdk does not exist
Error: package com.adjust.sdk does not exist
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BaseZendeskFeedbackConfiguration
  location: class my.super.project.Renderer
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BuildConfig
  location: package my.super.project
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Tracker
  location: class my.super.project.Main
Error: ';' expected
Error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error: package com.facebook does not exist
Error: package com.facebook.appevents does not exist
Error: package com.facebook.login does not exist
Error: package com.facebook.login does not exist
Error: package com.facebook.share.model does not exist
Error: package com.facebook.share.model does not exist
Error: package com.facebook.share.model does not exist
Error: package com.facebook.share.widget does not exist
Error: package com.facebook.share.widget does not exist
Error: package com.facebook.share.widget does not exist
Error: package twitter4j does not exist
Error: package twitter4j does not exist
Error: package twitter4j does not exist
Error: package twitter4j does not exist
Error: package twitter4j does not exist
Error: package twitter4j does not exist
Error: package twitter4j does not exist
Error: package twitter4j does not exist
Error: package twitter4j.auth does not exist
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class R
  location: package my.super.project
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AmazonGamesClient
  location: class my.super.project.Main
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MoPubRewardedVideoListener
  location: class my.super.project.Main
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ChartBoostDelegate
  location: class my.super.project.Main
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CallbackManager
  location: class my.super.project.ClassA
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ProfileTracker
  location: class my.super.project.ClassA

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

My `build.gradle` has the following tasks:

```
android {
    <snip>
    ['Main', 'Renderer', 'ClassA', 'ClassB'].each {
        def targetName ->
            tasks.create(name: "javahBuild_$targetName", type: Exec) {
                Properties properties = new Properties()
                properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
                String sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
                String flavorFolder = getCurrentFlavorFolder()
                commandLine 'javah', '-classpath', "libs/:src/main/java/:$sdkDir/platforms/android-23/android.jar:build/intermediates/classes/$flavorFolder/$config:$sdkDir/platforms/android-23/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar/:$config/", '-d', 'src/main/jni/Main/', "my.super.project.${targetName}"
            }
    }

    task javahBuildAll(dependsOn: tasks.matching { Task task -> task.name.startsWith("javahBuild_") })

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn javahBuildAll
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.5.1.2'

    compile('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0')
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0')
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0')
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0')
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0')
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0')
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.+')
    compile('io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.+')
    compile('com.batch.android:batch-sdk:1.5+')
    compile('com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.2.3')
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2')
}
```

Comment: I don't think your output should be interpreted as "javah works fine for a Java source but not another one". The visible result seems to be a result of running javah on two targets in parallel. If you run these tasks manually, you can verify or reject my assessment.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response. It was what I though first but running javah from the command line gives the same results: it works fine for ClassA, but not for ClassB.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, javah does not care about imports, and will only complain if it cannot determine a signature of a native method of the class that you ask it to process, and then the message in log is "Error: Cannot determine signature for …". Try to set `-classpath src/main/java` and you will see that yourself.

Comment: I do specify the class path actually and it doesn't help in any way, ClassA and ClassB are processed exactly the same way...

Comment: I am sure that javah cannot complain about non-existing packages. You can copy your ClassB outside the whole project and javah will process it just the same: `mkdir -p /tmp/my/super/project && cp src/main/java/my/super/project/ClassB.java /tmp/my/super/project && javah -cp /tmp my.super.project.ClassB`

Comment: Oh it's getting funnier: I did what you explained for both classes and now ClassB "compiles" just fine, but ClassA generates errors... I just realized I could forget about those errors since the header files still get generated. Ahem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it didn't understand why I'm getting those errors but I just realized I could ignore them since the C++ header files are still getting generated.

So I decide to modify my `javah` gradle task to ignore errors and write those into a dedicated log file. I've added the following line:

```
errorOutput = project.file("build/javah_error_${targetName}.log").newDataOutputStream()
ignoreExitValue = true
```

My `javah` task now looks like this:

```
['Main', 'Renderer', 'ClassA', 'ClassB'].each {
    def targetName ->
        tasks.create(name: "javahBuild_$targetName", type: Exec) {
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
            String sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
            String flavorFolder = getCurrentFlavorFolder()
            errorOutput = project.file("build/javah_error_${targetName}.log").newDataOutputStream()
            ignoreExitValue = true
            commandLine 'javah', '-classpath', "libs/:src/main/java/:$sdkDir/platforms/android-23/android.jar:build/intermediates/classes/$flavorFolder/$config:$sdkDir/platforms/android-23/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar/:$config/", '-d', 'src/main/jni/Main/', "my.super.project.${targetName}"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After multiple hours of searching, researching, trial and error, and other things, I’ve finally got it.

`javah` is gone, one must use `javac […] -h <destdir> […]` now.

I already had the following snippet in my top-level `build.gradle` (not the one under `app/` or so!) to [add `javac` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297051/2171120)…

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all"
}
```

… and “just” had to extend that. (This section goes into the `allprojects {` block which you already have in your top-level `build.gradle`, I put it after the `repositories { […] }` block.)

In my case, I merely wanted to let the `.h` files be created but not actively `#include` them in the C code (because I use [the `RegisterNatives` method](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#native-libraries) to register my functions), which would be… tricky, as one would *additionally* to this have to:

- figure out *which* of the (possibly multiple) tasks should create the `.h` files used in the actual build
- give *that* a stable pathname
- add *that* path to the include directories in the native build (again tricky)

For mere manual introspection, I just add the `javac -h <destdir>` option to *all* `javac` invocations, creating per-task result directories, and then just look at them in Midnight Commander:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all"
    options.getHeaderOutputDirectory().value(project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("headers/" + getName()))
}
```

(The `compilerArgs` change is, of course, copied unchanged from the above.)