# How to set custom Java compiler args on an Android project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, javac

I'm putting the following at the end of my project gradle file:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs += 
            ['-Xep:MissingOverride:ERROR', 
             '-Xep:MissingCasesInEnumSwitch:ERROR',]
    }
}
```

However, in my code if I remove an `@Override` annotation somewhere or remove a switch statement, my Android project still builds. Shouldn't it fail with an error?

Comment: I don't know if it behaves different for android projects but for our java EE build I implemented this: `compileJava{
  options.fork = true
  options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
  options.compilerArgs.addAll( [ '-APackageAcronym='+gradle.ext.packageAcronym, '-s', gradle.ext.generatedQueriesDir ] )
}` since compileJava is it's own task.

Comment: Do you put `compileJava` at the root level? If I do so in my case I get the following error message: "Error: Could not find method compileJava() ..."

Comment: Yes I put it at the root level. I think it's different for android gradle builds? Just thought to give it a shot :) Sorry I wasted you're time.

Comment: No, thanks for the suggestion! Appreciate you giving the time. :)

Comment: I googled a bit and it seems android really hides the task compileJava and denies access to it. But I found this peace which seems to work for other users `allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}` found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689365/how-to-add-xlintunchecked-to-my-android-gradle-based-project

information for compileJava task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853130/run-task-before-compilation-using-android-gradle-plugin

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works. Would you please write your comment as an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I googled your problem and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689365/how-to-add-xlintunchecked-to-my-android-gradle-based-project) 
that described your problem and the solution looks like this:

```
allprojects { 
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}
```

As is seems the gradle build is different for android projects than for java projects and you can't access the task `CompileJava` itself as stated in my first comment.

Comment: Sir, I salute you. This was a pain, and you solved it! I wonder why Android Studio does not have a clear option for that in the project settings. Anyway, thanks!